# error when using deploy, npm run deploy says no file found in directory use stack

Tags: javascript, java, deployment, discord

```bash
> discord-musicbot@5.0.0-beta deploy
> node deploy/deployGlobal
```

```
\\wsl.localhost\Debian\home\fatalog\Discord-MusicBot'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\deploy\deployGlobal'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

i wanted to run the deploy command to initiate node `index.js`

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Maybe you should [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit your question.